# Show the size according to the product in the cart in Ionic App

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am working on the Ionic Ecommerce App and I am showing the products with the size in the cart and some products have size and some don't have the size but the problem is that the products that doesn't have the size is showing the size label in the cart.

This is my **cart.html**:

```
<p *ngIf="ifSize">Size: {{itm?.psize}}</p>
```

In this view, I am showing the size for the products.

This is my **cart.ts**:

```
import { CheckoutPage } from './../checkout/checkout';
import { Component, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, LoadingController, AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { CartProvider } from "../../providers/cart/cart";

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-cart',
  templateUrl: 'cart.html',
})
export class CartPage {
 cartItems: any[] = [];
 totalAmount: number = 0;
 isCartItemLoaded: boolean = false;
 isEmptyCart: boolean = true;
 ifSize: boolean = true;
 productCount: number = 1;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private cartService: CartProvider, public loadingCtrl: LoadingController, private alertCtrl: AlertController, private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.loadCartItems();
  }

  loadCartItems() {
    let loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      content: "Wait.."
    });
    loader.present();
    this.cartService
      .getCartItems()
      .then(val => {
        this.cartItems = val;
        console.log(val);
        if(val.psize === undefined)
        {
        this.ifSize = false;
        }
        if (this.cartItems.length > 0) {
          this.cartItems.forEach((v, indx) => {
            this.totalAmount += parseInt(v.totalPrice);
          });
          this.cdr.detectChanges();
          this.isEmptyCart = false;
        }
        this.isCartItemLoaded = true;
        loader.dismiss();
      })
      .catch(err => {});
  }
}
```

In this ts file, By default it will show the size for all the products and the products that doesn't have the size for that the size label will hide. But the problem is that console.log(val); is coming like the array of products. So that's why I am not able to find the size of the products in the array and also not able to apply the correct condition for the size in the array of the products. Any help is much appreciated. **Result of:**

> console.log(val);

[image]

Comment: what ifSize print when size is undefined

Comment: @sunielkalwani. Initially it is true. ifSize: boolean = true; after that if it is undefined. It will be false.

Comment: just use < p *ngIf="itm.psize">Size: {{itm.psize}}< /p> .You needn't has two variables for the same work

Comment: @Eliseo. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`val.psize` doesnt return anything in your case because you need `val[0].psize, val[1].psize` so on... To solve this problem, remove this one:

```
 if(val.psize === undefined)
        {
         this.ifSize = false;
        }
```

Add here `v.psize` and check inside the foreach like this:

```
if (this.cartItems.length > 0) {
          this.cartItems.forEach((v, indx) => {

    //---Add here 
            if(v.psize===undefined){
              this.ifSize = false;
            }else{
              this.ifSize = true;
            }
    //---
            this.totalAmount += parseInt(v.totalPrice);
          });
          this.cdr.detectChanges();
          this.isEmptyCart = false;
        }
```

then your code should work as expected

**Edit**:
Maybe your looking this one, I m kinda confused:

```
<p *ngIf="itm?.psize!== undefined">Size: {{itm?.psize}}</p>
```

Comment: This is showing the product sizes but Not able to hide the size label for the products.

Comment: I m not sure what do you mean? can you upload full html too. Because over here your displaying `itm?.psize` which means probably product sizes. Did you try the code because your `val.psize` doesnt mean anything?

Comment: <p *ngIf="ifSize">Size: {{itm?.psize}}</p>. In this it is taking the final ifSize value for all the products like if the last product added has undefined size then it will hide the size label for all the products in the cart.

Comment: where do you define `itm?.psize` on the ts ?

Comment: I got the problem if one product has size and one not so it will set the ifSize  to false and all the products size label will hide. So , can we define ifSize according to the products.

Comment: this.cartItems = val; This contains the psize attribute. and I am running the loop in the Html. <ion-list *ngFor="let itm of cartItems" class="myitem11">

Comment: This doesn't make any sense if you're trying to display total size. You need to make a `Totalsize` and add eact itm?.psize to that let me edit the answer.

Comment: Like I am not trying to display the totalsize. Each product has it own size. If the size of the product exists it will show the size label for that product and if the product doesn't have the size, if will hide the size label for that product.

Comment: than you should keep changing `true`, `false` foreach item . I updated the answer check and try than let me know.

Comment: Thank you very much for your alternative answer. It has worked now.

Comment: And the problem in the if else condition, if the last added product is true and it will set all the true and vice versa.

Comment: Once again Thank you for the answer.